# How to receive a local notification in the background when a firebase message is received

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm making a chat app in SwiftUI and Firebase Firestore, I am using Firestore to fetch all messages. What I would like to do now is, whenever the user receives a message from another user (in the background), send a local notification, with app refresh and background tasks.

This is my code to send a local notification (works):

```swift
func scheduleCustomNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "New Message"
    content.body = "You have a new message from John Doe."
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0, repeats: false)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Custom notification scheduled successfully.")
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried doing app refreshing, but `backgroundTask` is not working.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct SimplePhoneApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Main()
        }
        .onChange(of: phase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .background: scheduleAppRefresh()
            default: break
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("myapprefresh")) {
            print("background task")
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        print("app refresh")
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "myapprefresh")
        request.earliestBeginDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(2)
        try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    }
}

// other code
```

Comment: That strategy isn't going to work. A background app refresh task won't execute frequently or often enough. Use push notifications from a server.